# Got delegate nil error even it was set in the main viewcontroller

Tags: swift, delegates, protocols

I have simple app which the welcomeVC shows a greeting message with a person's name. In another VC nameVC, users can change the name they want to be called, and it supposes to update the name on the welcomeVC when they click back.

In order to pass the name from nameVC back to welcomeVC, I set up a protocol ChangeNameDelegate in nameVC, and created a variable in my class:

```
protocol ChangeNameDelegate {
    func updateName(name: String)
}
class nameViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    var changeNameDelegate: ChangeNameDelegate!
    override func viewDidLoad() {

    }

    @IBAction func closeNameVC(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let newName = nameTextField.text {
            changeNameDelegate.updateName(name: newName)
        }

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

In my welcomeVC, I have made sure that it register the delegate and conforms to the protocol by setting up as follows:

```
class welcomeViewController: UIViewController, UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
let nameVC = nameViewController()
override func viewDidLoad() {
       nameVC.changeNameDelegate = self
    }
}
extension welcomeViewController: ChangeNameDelegate {
    func updateName(name: String) {
        print("The name has been updated!")
        nameLabel.text = name
    }

}
```

However when I ran my app, it got a crash because changeNameDelegate appeared to be nil. Does anybody know what could be missed there? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are instantiating **new** instance of NameViewController when routing from WelcomeViewController. You should navigate to nameVC which is instantiated before.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my code: 

    public override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        let nameVC = segue.destination as? nameViewController
        nameVC?.changeNameDelegate = self
        
    }
however the problem is still existing. Dont know what's wrong here.

Comment: In storyboard, did you set your NameViewController class as custom class at identity inspector?

Comment: Yes. It has set to the custom class.  I realized that I really don't have a segue from welcomeVC to nameVC, so I changed to refer the nameVC from stroyboard, using 
```
let nameVC: nameViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NameVC") as! nameViewController
 nameVC.changeNameDelegate = self
`` 
 but it didn't help much, the delegate is still nil ;(

Comment: Can you share full implementation of both view controllers and a screenshot of your storyboard?

Comment: Sure, thank you for your help. Can I PM you the link of my project?

Answer (score -1):

I later solved the issue by using notification/observer.

In the parent view:

```
    let userUpdateNotification = Notification.Name(rawValue: "nameNotificationKey")
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:  #selector(updateUser), name: userUpdateNotification, object: nil)
    }

func updateUser(not: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = not.userInfo {
        if let userName = userInfo["name"] as? String {
            nameLabel.text = userName
        }
    }
}
```

In the child view:

```
   let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: "nameNotificationKey")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: name , object: self, userInfo: ["name": nameTextField.text!] )
        }
```

I don't know if delegate/protocol doesn't work between view controllers that are unconnected. Anyone who knows about this is welcomed to comment!

Comment: That's a lazy way out. They are not "unconnected." There is a relationship between these two view controllers. They _have_ a way to talk to each other. You just need to be clear on what that relationship _is_. It would be better to store the name in user defaults, or some other commonly available dropbox, than to use a notification for _this_.